Converting this preg_replace to match a word with a plus
In PHP I need to highlight multiple given words in a string, for example wrapping found matches inside a <em> tag.
But if I have a word ending in + I cannot do it.
I understand the below problem is that plus is not a word and breaks that \b flag word match. But how can I write this so that it matches and wrapps all given words even if a given word ends in + ?
$my_text = 'test c+ and javascript etc but NOT javascripter';

$words_to_highlight = array('javascript', 'c+');


foreach($words_to_highlight as $word){
    
    $search_pattern = str_replace('+', '\\+', $word);
    
    // this doesn't match replacement
    echo "\n".preg_replace("/\b(".$search_pattern.")\b/i", '<em>$1</em>', $my_text);
    
    // works if I remove the \b flag, but I don't want to match "javascript" inside "javascripter"
    echo "\n".preg_replace("/(".$search_pattern.")/i", '<em>$1</em>', $my_text);
    
}

Output is:
test c+ and <em>javascript</em> etc but NOT javascripter
test c+ and <em>javascript</em> etc but NOT <em>javascript</em>er

test c+ and javascript etc but NOT javascripter
test <em>c+</em> and javascript etc but NOT javascripter

What I want to result is:
test <em>c+</em> and <em>javascript</em> etc but NOT javascripter


Instead of using word boundaries, you can make use of whitspace boundaries in the form of lookarounds asserting not a non whitspace character to the left (?<!\S) and the right (?!\S)
For escaping characters which are part of the regex syntax, you can use preg_quote.
To to the replacement with a single pattern that matches all the words, you can dynamically create the regex with a non capture group listing all the alternatives separated by a pipe char |
The final pattern would look like this:
(?<!\S)(?:javascript|c\+)(?!\S)

See the matches in a regex demo and a PHP demo.
As you are not matching other text, you don't need a capture group and you can use the full match in the replacement denoted by $0
For example:
$my_text = 'test c+ and / javascript etc but NOT javascripter';
$words_to_highlight = array('javascript', 'c+');
$pattern = sprintf(
    "/(?<!\S)(?:%s)(?!\S)/i",
    implode('|',
        array_map(function ($s) {
            return preg_quote($s, '/');
        }, $words_to_highlight)));

echo preg_replace($pattern, '<em>$0</em>', $my_text);

Output
test <em>c+</em> and <em>javascript</em> etc but NOT javascripter

If you are using PHP 7.4 or higher you can make use of an arrow function for array_map
 array_map(fn($s) => preg_quote($s, '/'), $words_to_highlight)


Another idea is to make a little helper function that generates a regex pattern from each word and only ads word boundaries if there are word-characters at ^ start | or $ end of the string.
function w_to_regex ($w) {
  return '/'.preg_replace('/^\b|$\b/', '\b', preg_quote($w,'/')).'/i';
}

Further preg_quote() is used to escape regex-characters. The patterns will look like:

/\bjavascript\b/i
/\bc\+/i

Add the u-flag if it's UTF-8. You can use array_map to generate patterns and replace.
$my_text = preg_replace(array_map('w_to_regex', $words), '<em>$0</em>', $my_text);

See a PHP demo at tio.run - the result will be like this:
test <em>c+</em> and <em>javascript</em> etc but NOT javascripter
Note that one of the differences in my and the 4th bird's answer is, that this one would highlight e.g. c+ in c++ which can be desired or not. However you have some different options and ideas.

My advice resembles bobblebubble's.  You can use a lookahead at the start of the pattern to determine if a word boundary or a non-word boundary should be used before the needle string. Use a lookbehind at the end of the string to again determine which kind of zero-width boundary should be applied.
Code: (Demo)
$my_text = 'test c+ and javascript etc but NOT javascripter';

$words_to_highlight = ['javascript', 'c+'];

echo preg_replace(
         '#(?=\b\w|\B\W)(?:' . implode('|', array_map(preg_quote(...), $words_to_highlight)) . ')(?<=\w\b|\W\B)#i',
         '<em>$0</em>',
         $my_text
     );

Output:
test <em>c+</em> and <em>javascript</em> etc but NOT javascripter

As bobblebubble stated, this pattern will match the partial term c+ if c++ is found in the string.  You will need to clarify your desired logic (and extend your minimal verifiable example) if this is not desirable.
